# how to make volley onResponse run in UnitTest thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-volley, realm

i'm making unit test for my application
my unit test class has this method

```
@Before
public void initialize() {
    mContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(mContext).name("realmTest").inMemory().build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
    mWorkoutsModel = new WorkoutsModel(mContext);
    mRealm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
    mWorkoutsModel.registerListener(this);
}

@Test
public void getWorkouts() throws Exception {
    mWorkoutsModel.onStart();

    mLock.await();
    mWorkoutsModel.onStop();

}

@After
public void deInitialize() {
    mWorkoutsModel.unRegisterListener();
    mRealm.close();
}
```

and my model

```
@Override
public void onStart() {

    mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        getDataFromApi();
}

private boolean getDataFromApi() {
    Constants.AllAPIs.ALLWorkouts allWorkouts = new Constants.AllAPIs.ALLWorkouts();
    if (Permissions.isInternetConnectionExist(mContext)) {
        mApiHandler.downLoadDataFromApi(AllWorkouts.class, allWorkouts.getBaseUrl(),
                new APIHandler.StringResponseHandler<AllWorkouts>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(AllWorkouts response) {
                            insertWorkouts(response.getWorkouts());
                },
                new APIHandler.ErrorResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }, TAG);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
private void insertWorkouts(final List<Workout> workouts) {
    mCurrentInsertTransaction = mRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
            bgRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(workouts);
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
        }
    });
}
```

my problem that the unittest calls onStart which create realm object in the model in test thread but volley force onResponse to run on UIThread which makes realm throw exception `Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.`

the code runs perfect in normal, but in test it fails

does anyone faced same problem or can solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved my problem by run the test in handler

```
new Handler(mContext.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                mWorkoutsModel.onStart();
                mLock.await();
                mWorkoutsModel.onStop();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

hope that help somebody

Comment: Thanks bro .its work for me.so i can do heavy task in seprate thread so my ui is not blocked.can you give deatils explanation of handler class.like when to use ,why and how